# PostGIS max contains query

Tags: postgis

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE periphereies
(
  gid serial NOT NULL,
  per character varying(60),
  geom geometry(MultiPolygon),
  CONSTRAINT periphereies_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gid)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE TABLE archaia_theatra
(
  gid serial NOT NULL,
  "ΘΕΑΤΡΟ" character varying(254),
  "X" numeric,
  "Y" numeric,
  geom geometry(Point),
  CONSTRAINT archaia_theatra_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gid)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

First of all i am trying to write a query that return's me all the periphereies record's that contain at least one archaia_theatra.geom point record..
Then i want to select the periphereies which contains the maximum number of archaia_theatra (compared with all the other perifereies records)

I am trying this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW per_max_theatra AS
SELECT count(p.per) FROM periphereies AS p JOIN archaia_theatra AS a ON
ST_Contains(p.geom, a.geom) ORDER BY count(p.per) DESC LIMIT 1
```

but it's not working

Any help?

Comment: what is error? btw your view is only count(p.per) without any relation to p sso , maybe add p.id there or something ?

Comment: @simplexio SELECT * FROM per_max_theatra returns 40 but 40 is all the archaia_theatra records (and it's a wrong answer)

Comment: see @micha answer. select p.geom, count(p.per) ... group by a.geom. would return all a.geoms and count of p.geom which are inside of p.geom

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a `GROUP BY p.gid` in a WHERE clause.